# How to add/remove class using bullets and arrows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble figuring out how to add and remove a class from a div when a user clicks either on its corresponding number or the prev/next arrows.

Notice the 'active' class on the second item as well as the second nav. I would like the class to be removed and added to the first item and nav when a user clicks the "1" or the "previous" arrow.

```css
.wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav a {
  padding: 5px;
}
.nav a:hover {
  font-weight: 900;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav a.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-weight: 900;
}

.prev, .next {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  font-weight: 900;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.items div {
  display: none;
  padding: 25px;
}
.items .one {
  background: red;
}
.items .two {
  background: green;
}
.items .three {
  background: blue;
}
.items .active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="nav">
    <a class="one">1</a>
    <a class="two active">2</a>
    <a class="three">3 </a>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <span class="prev"><</span>
    <div class="one">ONE</div>
    <div class="two active">TWO</div>
    <div class="three">THREE</div>
    <span class="next">></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/bbbenji/pen/WovJEM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try somethinglike this:

```js
$('.next, .prev').on('click', function() {
  var $cur = $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.items div.active');
  var $nav = $(this).closest('.wrap').find(' .nav a.active')

  if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
    if ($cur.next('div').length === 0) return
    $cur.next('div').addClass('active');
    $nav.next('a').addClass('active');
  } else {
    if ($cur.prev('div').length === 0) return
    $cur.prev('div').addClass('active');
    $nav.prev('a').addClass('active');
  }
  $cur.removeClass('active')
  $nav.removeClass('active')
})

$('.nav a').on('click', function() {
  var index = $(this).index();
  $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.items div').removeClass('active').eq(index).addClass('active')
  $(this).closest('.wrap').find('.nav a').removeClass('active').eq(index).addClass('active')
})
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav a {
  padding: 5px;
}
.nav a:hover {
  font-weight: 900;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav a.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.prev,
.next {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  font-weight: 900;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.items div {
  display: none;
  padding: 25px;
}
.items .one {
  background: red;
}
.items .two {
  background: green;
}
.items .three {
  background: blue;
}
.items .active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="nav">
    <a class="one">1</a>
    <a class="two active">2</a>
    <a class="three">3 </a>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <span class="prev"><</span>
    <div class="one">ONE</div>
    <div class="two active">TWO</div>
    <div class="three">THREE</div>
    <span class="next">></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
  <div class="nav">
    <a class="one">1</a>
    <a class="two active">2</a>
    <a class="three">3 </a>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <span class="prev"><</span>
    <div class="one">ONE</div>
    <div class="two active">TWO</div>
    <div class="three">THREE</div>
    <span class="next">></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Clicking on the numbers does not work

Comment: @Weedoze Thanks for pointing out. Please check the update

Comment: Now it is beautiful hehe

Comment: @Weedoze I was actually trying for `toggleClass` with expression, but little confused of how to compare current index with index

Comment: That works great. But what what if there were multiple `div.wrap`? It looks like they would both be controlled by the same arrows. But only the first one by the numbers.

http://codepen.io/bbbenji/pen/woaxMv

Comment: @Rajesh I've tried something different. See my answer. Did you mean that by toggle class ?

Comment: @bskool I have updated my answer to handle multiple wraps

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it using an `index`

```js
var classes = ["one", "two", "three"];
var currentIndex = 1;

$('.next, .prev').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('next')) {
    if (currentIndex === classes.length - 1) return;
    removeAndAddActive(currentIndex, ++currentIndex);
  } else {
    if (currentIndex === 0) return;
    removeAndAddActive(currentIndex, --currentIndex);
  }
})

$('.nav a').on('click', function() {
  let index = $(this).index();
  removeAndAddActive(currentIndex, index);
  currentIndex = index;
})

function removeAndAddActive(removeIndex, addIndex) {
  $('.' + classes[removeIndex]).removeClass('active');
  $('.' + classes[addIndex]).addClass('active');
}
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.nav {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav a {
  padding: 5px;
}
.nav a:hover {
  font-weight: 900;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.nav a.active {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  font-weight: 900;
}
.prev,
.next {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
}
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  font-weight: 900;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.items div {
  display: none;
  padding: 25px;
}
.items .one {
  background: red;
}
.items .two {
  background: green;
}
.items .three {
  background: blue;
}
.items .active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="nav">
    <a class="one">1</a>
    <a class="two active">2</a>
    <a class="three">3 </a>
  </div>
  <div class="items">
    <span class="prev"><</span>
    <div class="one">ONE</div>
    <div class="two active">TWO</div>
    <div class="three">THREE</div>
    <span class="next">></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason this would be better than the one chosen as the answer? As far as I see this is less desirable as the chosen solution doesn't need each item's class defined in the script to work.

Comment: If OP plans to add say 10 more divs, this will enforce updating array. I would suggest using currently clicked element and then navigating to necessary element

Comment: @bskool Not at all, I wanted to propose another solution using a different thinking

Comment: @Rajesh You're right

Comment: @Weedoze Thank you!

Comment: @Weedoze I have updated your solution. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jcna9ypj/).

Comment: @Rajesh I dont see the update in my solution

Comment: @Weedoze I meant I have updated in JSFiddle. :-p

Comment: @Rajesh ahah sorry I did not even saw the JSFiddle